# Add 0 in the middle of a filename

Tags: bash, shell, rename

```
$ ls
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_11_descriptiveadjectives.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_12_nationality.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_1_campus.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_2_personnes.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_3_presentations.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_4_identifier.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_5_bonjouraurevoir.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_6_commentcava.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_7_expressionspolitesse.mp3
```

I would like to add '0' before the numbers in the middle so that they are sorted as in

```
$ ls -v
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_1_campus.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_2_personnes.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_3_presentations.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_4_identifier.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_5_bonjouraurevoir.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_6_commentcava.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_7_expressionspolitesse.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_11_descriptiveadjectives.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_12_nationality.mp3
```

What I have so far is

```
$ for i in *.mp3; do echo ${i/_[0-9]_/_0¿_}; done
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_11_descriptiveadjectives.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_12_nationality.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_campus.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_personnes.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_presentations.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_identifier.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_bonjouraurevoir.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_commentcava.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_0¿_expressionspolitesse.mp3
```

I don't know what should be put in place of '¿' so that the number that matched [0-9] appears there instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes a specific solution is good enough; like in the current case where you can identify the patterns for the file subset to consider (e.g `/_[0-9]_/`) and add a leading zero depending on a uniquely identifying prefix (e.g. `/re_/`). Put all together that would be:

```
for f in *_[0-9]_*.mp3 ; do mv -i "${f}" "${f/re_/re_0}" ; done
```

For the pre-check you asked for you can add an `echo` in front of the `mv`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `rename` from `util-linux` too:

```
rename vocabulaire_ vocabulaire_0 *vocabulaire_[0-9]_*.mp3
```

result:

```
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_01_campus.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_02_personnes.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_12_nationality.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_231_whatever.mp3
```

if you wish to further zero-pad repeat the command increasing the number of digits:

```
rename vocabulaire_ vocabulaire_0 *vocabulaire_[0-9][0-9]_*.mp3
```

result:

```
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_001_campus.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_002_personnes.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_012_nationality.mp3
pro2e_u01_txt_vocabulaire_231_whatever.mp3
```

Comment: Your solution looks cleanest but I chose the other answer because of the possibility to check it before actually doing it. Thanks for answer with detailed example.

Comment: @user107459 - no problem; unfortunately this command doesn't support `--test`; someone proposed a patch a [couple of years ago](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2013-12/msg00157.html) with many useful enhancements (`--force`, `--no-clobber`, `--dry-run` etc). While the request to move the command from `util-linux` to `coreutils` was rejected for good reason, the fact that none of those features was included in `rename` is really odd.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, Ubuntu and other systems where `rename` is a Perl script (as opposed to the one in util-linux), this command will be sufficient as long as the files are from 1 to 99.

```
rename 's/_vocabulaire_([0-9]{1})_/_vocabulaire_0$1_/' *.mp3
```

If you want to just do a dry-run without renaming the files pass in the -n option. It will show what will actually be renamed

```
rename -n 's/_vocabulaire_([0-9]{1})_/_vocabulaire_0$1_/' *.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to check it like "echo" when "mv" is used, before actually trying it? `for i in *.mp3; do echo ${i/_([0-9]{1})_/_0$1_}; done` did not work.

Comment: Using rename command you can't do that. Give me a few minutes, I will get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Some versions of `rename` support `-n` to show what would be renamed. Run `rename --help` to know for sure. (Some versions of `rename` have a completely different syntax, too.)

Comment: There does not seem to be '-n' in my version. The bottom of man page for rename says "June 2011".

Comment: rename from util-linux 2.25.2

Comment: That version of `rename` doesn't support the syntax given in this answer, unfortunately (it takes two fixed strings as parameters to search for and replace with, rather than a single Perl expression). In this case, it's probably easiest to use the other provided answer, which relies only on bash.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in ./*.mp3
do    set "${f%_*}" "_${f##*_}"; f=10${1##*_}
      mv "$1$2" "${1%_*}_${f#*$((${#f}<4))}$2"
done
```

That should work, I think, so long as your number field is between the last and second-to-last `_` divided field and given you only wish to pad to 2 digit places.

Answer (score 1):

For the following files:

```
test0.txt
test1.txt
test2.txt
...
test1234.txt
```

This worked for me:

```
rename 's/test([0-9]{1}).txt/test0$1.txt/' *
rename 's/test([0-9]{2}).txt/test0$1.txt/' *
rename 's/test([0-9]{3}).txt/test0$1.txt/' *
```

Result:

```
test0000.txt
test0001.txt
test0002.txt
...
test1234.txt
```

Of course you can wrap it inside a loop.

**Important:** If your files begin or end with numbers that you want to pad, you have to use `^` and `$` to match with beginning and end, e.g.:

```
rename 's/^([0-9]{1}).txt/0$1.txt/' *
```

or

```
rename 's/test([0-9]{1})$/test0$1/' *
```

You can use `rename`'s `-n` parameter to preview changes without actual renaming, e.g.:

```
rename -n 's/test([0-9]{1}).txt/test0$1.txt/' *
```